# Qt 5 Unknown module(s) in QT: uitools

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

I just started to use Qt today and I don't know if I did something wrong when I installed it but I can't use `QFormBuilder`.

*Linux Xubuntu 64b*

what I did:

- I clone this repo : git@gitorious.org:qt/qt5.git
- init_repository >> ./configure >> make >> sudo make install
- I downloaded qt-creator http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator
- I created a new project and when I try to include `QFormBuilder` he tell me that he doesn't know this file.

So, I saw somewhere someone who says that I need to add `QT += uitools` to the project file, but now when I try to use `qmake`,  I am getting `Unknown module(s) in QT: uitools`.

Sorry for my english and thank you for your help.

Comment: On Ubuntu, check that `apt-get install libqt5designer5 qttools5-dev` are installed: https://github.com/pgmodeler/pgmodeler/issues/385

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually read the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qformbuilder.html)?

It writes this at the beginning:

> The QFormBuilder class is used to dynamically construct user interfaces from UI files at run-time. More...
>
> Header:   #include
>
> qmake:    QT += designer
>
> Inherits: QAbstractFormBuilder.

So, just follow that and put this into your qmake project file:

```
QT += designer
```

or you can invoke `qmake` like this:

```
qmake QT += designer
```

Of course, you need to make sure that you have the designer installed properly for this. You will need to install a package like `libqt5designer5` on your Ubuntu, or if you had installed Qt manually, you will need to install the designer manually as well.

I am not that familiar with Ubuntu. You may need to install some corresponding development package as well. Either way, the point is that the library and headers need to be installed properly on your system which you seem to lack when getting `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: designer` after either of the aforementioned solutions.

Answer (score 56):

If you get

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: designer
```

you are missing `qttools5-dev` package.

Comment: This worked straightaway. In RHEL 7.3 I had to install `qt5-qttools-devel` and it worked.

Comment: On CENTOS 7.5 I needed also qt5-qttools-static

Comment: And the fix applies to OP's problem of *`Qt 5 Unknown module(s) in QT: uitools`*.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer by @svlasov, on RHEL or CentOS based systems (7.x or 8.x, etc.) you need to install:

```
yum install qt5-qttools-devel
```

Depending on the project you are building, you may also need to install `qt5-qttools-static`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qformbuilder.html), it says to add the designer module to the .pro file:

> QT += designer